# Python: Files downloading into the wrong location

Tags: python

I'm using the code below to create a folder and then download the assocated PDBs with that protein. The problem I'm having is the PDBs are downloaded into the wrong location. They are downloaded into the loaction with the python script and not into the Cytochrome_C folder.

```
pdb = [
['Cytochrome_C']
['1giw','TITLE']
['1lc1','TITLE']
['1lc2','TITLE']
]

for pdb in pdbs:

    if str(pdb[0]) == 'Cytochrome_C':
        os.popen('mkdir Cytochrome_C')
        os.popen('cd ./Cytochrome_C')


    if len(pdb) == 2:
        os.popen('wget http://www.pdb.org/pdb/files/%s.pdb' % (str(pdb[0])))
```

Comment: os.Popen is unnecessary for every one of those tasks.  Look into `shutil`, os.chdir, and urllib2

Comment: The `popen()` for **cd** command is useless because it will only change directory for the session created by popen. Please consider the libraries @chown pointed you to.

Comment: plus, you probably want the first line to be 'pdbs = ['

Comment: With what you currently have, there's no point to doing this in python. Just use bash..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

os.popen is unnecessary for every one of those tasks. Use shutil and urllib2:

```
pdb = [
['Cytochrome_C']
['1giw','TITLE']
['1lc1','TITLE']
['1lc2','TITLE']
]
cwd = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())

for pdb in pdbs:
    if pdb[0] == 'Cytochrome_C':
        shutil.mkdir(os.path.join(cwd, pdb[0]))

    if len(pdb) == 2:
        s = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.pdb.org/pdb/files/%s.pdb' % pdb[0]).read()
        open(os.path.join(cwd, 'Cytochrome_C', '%s.pdb' % pdb[0]), "w").write(s)
```

Comment: @ThomasK Interesting.  I usually only ever use urllib for `quote_plus()`/`urlencode()` and similar functions, never for opening a url.  Ill have to check that out now though, thanks!